# UITableView not rendering

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

So I have a UITableView as a subview of another view in interface builder, and it is not rendering. I've already checked that the number of sections method is returning 1, and that the number of rows in section method is returning a number > 0.

This is my code -

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad{
    //[super viewDidLoad];
    _trendingImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"trending.png"];
    [self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.scrollView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;

    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"RecommendationCell"
                                bundle:nil];
    [self.recommendationsTableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier: reco

    recommendationCellIdentifier];
        self.recommendationsTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    }


-(void)executeRecSearch{
    @try{
        [AJAXUtils getAsyncJsonWithUrl:(NSURL *)[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:someUrl]] callback:^(NSDictionary *returnjson){
            if(returnjson != nil){
                self.recommendations = returnjson[@"Node"][@"Recommendations"][@"Components"];
                NSLog(@"COUNT: %d", [self.recommendations count]);
                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(renderRecommendations) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
            }

        }];

    } @catch (NSException* e) {

    }
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)sections{
    return [self.recommendations count];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

-(void)renderRecommendations{
    self.recommendationsTableView.hidden = FALSE;
    [self.recommendationsTableView reloadData];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"CELL INDEX PATH CALLED: %@", self.recommendations);
    RecommendationCell *cell = [self.recommendationsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:recommendationCellIdentifier];

    if(self.recommendations != nil){
        NSDictionary* recommendationData = self.recommendations[indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I also checked that the delegate and dataSource were linked to the File's Owner in the connections manager.

Why is the draw method not being called?

This is my .h file

```
@interface BasicCardViewController : UIViewController<RateViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

@property(atomic)NSInteger rating;

@property(copy,nonatomic)NSString *userPageLink;
@property(copy,nonatomic)NSString *nodePage;
@property(strong, nonatomic)NSString* description;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString* pageScore;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString* pageTitle;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString* phoneNumber;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString* address;
@property(weak,nonatomic)NSArray* recommendations;
@property(atomic)NSInteger* numberOfRecommendations;


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet TooviaRateView *rateView;
@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView *restaurantImageView;
@property(strong,nonatomic)UIImage* restaurantImage;
@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UITextView* descriptionView;
@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView* trendingImageView;
@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel* pageScoreLabel;
@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel* pageTitleLabel;
@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIScrollView* scrollView;
@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel* phoneNumberLabel;
@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel* addressLabel;
@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UITableView* recommendationsTableView;

- (IBAction)logOut:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)writeRecommendation:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)call:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)map:(id)sender;

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)sections;
@end
```

This is what I get when I print out data source and delegate-

```
2013-12-17 17:58:41.473 ReviewApp[17451:a0b] DATA SOURCE : *nil description*
2013-12-17 17:58:41.473 ReviewApp[17451:a0b] Data Delegate : *nil description*
```

Comment: and did you enter your class where you implement the delegate and datasource as a subclass of files owner in interface builder ? Oh and is your nibWithName string correct and also set in the interface builder ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: see this : http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-YmNJJGkKse8/T45RrlWKP6I/AAAAAAAAAAA/__9pTnujWX8/s640/Screen%2Bshot%2B2011-11-25%2Bat%2B10.56.10%2BPM.png

Comment: I see a field called Custom Class, with the class set to the controller

Comment: print [self.recommendations count] in your numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: it is 2 - I also thought it could be because the table view is not scrolled in yet, and moved it up, but the same issue is there

Comment: In your .h do you implement `<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>` Try making a property of your UITableView connect this in your Interface Builder and in your `viewDidLoad` call `[setDelegate:self];` and corresponding for datasource

Comment: I've added my .h file - is that what you meant?

Comment: ahhh ok so I did that - and I get DATA SOURCE : *nil description*
 Data Delegate : *nil description* - does that mean the data source and delegate weren't set, or does that mean there is nothing to print for that object?

Comment: I have a viewWillAppear method as well - will that cause any problems?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create the cell in

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`
will return nil if no cell is available to dequeue.

Modify it to something similar to this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"CELL INDEX PATH CALLED: %@", self.recommendations);
    RecommendationCell *cell = [self.recommendationsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:recommendationCellIdentifier];

    if(cell==nil){
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
    }

    if(self.recommendations != nil){
        NSDictionary* recommendationData = self.recommendations[indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: yeah, but the cell for row at index path method is not even called

Comment: And `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` or `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)sections` are called?

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection is called - I checked this by doing a NSLog

Comment: Try adding `self.recommendationsTableView.dataSource=self` inside `viewDidLoad`

Comment: well I have a viewWillAppear method - does that interfere with viewDidLoad? I added this in my viewDidLoad, and nothing -

    [self.recommendationsTableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.recommendationsTableView setDataSource:self];

Comment: and if you print `self.recommendationsTableView` is it nil?

Comment: yeah - I get this <UITableView: 0x9a25400; frame = (1 720; 318 221); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8d55170>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8d55a30>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43317/discussion-between-praks5432-and-slecorne)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, none of the provided examples worked, so I rolled out a a simple delay function.

```
class func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
    }
}}

func renderCategories () {

    Utils.delay(1) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

After a ton of stuff - this worked -

I checked use autolayout for the table view(it had been unchecked before, I guess because this view exists inside of a scroll view, and I had unchecked autolayout for that). It then drew - I have no idea why.