# UITableView not rendering without autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

So I have a TableView that sits inside a scroll view. I have autolayout turned off so I can scroll. However, the table view does not render when autolayout is turned off(the cellForIndexAtPath method is not called).

I need the table view to be scrolled to -

[UITableView not rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630487/uitableview-not-rendering)

has all the code.

Thanks

Comment: have you check connection of tableview and check datasource and delegate of it.

Comment: and why tableView inside a scrollView???
tablview is subclass of scrollview.

Comment: because I have different things to display that need to be scrolled voer?

Answer (score 0):

To check if the table and scroll view are added in the nib file, you can try assigning different background colours to them temporarily. If the components are visible, check if you have connected their delegate and datasource connections to file owner.
Hope this helps.